# How to get PyAudio to consistently generate OSError when the input device is disconnected?

Tags: usb, pyaudio

I am attempting to record an audio stream from a USB audio microphone using the blocking `stream.read()` function from PyAudio in a while loop. I want an exception to be thrown when the USB connection is broken but am getting inconsistent behavior across OS environments.

Here is my test code:

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,channels=1,rate=48000,frames_per_buffer=48000,input_device_index=1,input=True)
while True:
  data = stream.read(48000)
  print("looping")
```

On Windows this code successfully throws an `OSError` on disconnection that occurs within the loop. On Ubuntu and MacOS the read() function hangs indefinitely.

How can I achieve consistent behavior? At present I am considering moving to a multiprocessing solution that uses a parallel watchdog process to detect USB disconnections (which will likely require OS-specific implementations e.g. pyudev) and will force kill the recording process when disconnection is detected.